# Impact of leaving too much disabled accounts on Active Directory server

Tags: active-directory

I'm having around 2000 Inactive account on AD server.
For some reasons, we cannot remove these accounts out of system.
I'm not see any impact when leaving a huge amount of those inactivate account in our AD server except of slow loading and cannot show all users when we access to the UserOU folder.
So what I consider now is that if any impact to the performance of AD sever later on or any risk when leaving this much disabled accounts?

Answer (score 0):

It should be no problem, but you might still to consider to delete them as described at https://serverfault.com/questions/64175/active-directory-delete-vs-disable-departed-employees

Note, keeping accounts might impact licensing (quote from above link)

> that accounts in your AD require a "per-seat" license (if you are
>   swinging that way), whether or not they are a real person and whether
>   or not the person is still present. So there is an argument to be made
>   for deletion!

Comment: Yeah, I think so but just want to hear from external resources.